# How to get a response with an AT command via ADB?

Tags: adb, gsm, at-command

I was doing what suggested here: [Sending AT Commands Via ADB Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12855482/sending-at-commands-via-adb-android)

So after I rooted my Samsung S5, I found my modem with this command: `getprop rild.libargs` and I got this result: **-d /dev/smd0**

Then I typed into my adb shell: `echo -c "AT\r\n" > /dev/smd0`

But nothing is returned.

I don't understand, any idea ?

I also tried other commands like: `AT+CREG or AT+COPS=?`, still nothing.

Comment: I don't know if after three years makes still sense, but according to AT commands specification each command is terminated by a `\r`, not by an `\r\n`.

Comment: Furthermore, you should send  first `cat /dev/smd0 &`, in order to catch any data from modem's port.